# javascript object properties passing to asp.net mvc JsonResult actionmethod always null

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, asp.net-mvc-4

I been trying to pass the array of objects to JsonResult action method created on Controller class, I tried all possible solution from different answer but none work. 
Here is my js function:

```
function CalculateCost() {
var distancecost = [];
//prepare the List<DistanceCost> object
for (i = 0; i < _SELECTED_POINTS.length; i++) {
    console.log('point::' + _SELECTED_POINTS[i]);
    let dist = {
        PlaceId: _SELECTED_POINTS[i].place_id,
        PointSequence: _SELECTED_POINTS[i].PointSequence,
        controlId: _SELECTED_POINTS[i].controlId,
        FromLatitude: (i == (_SELECTED_POINTS.length - 1)) ? _SELECTED_POINTS[0].geometry.location.lat() : _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lat(),
        FromLongitude: (i == (_SELECTED_POINTS.length - 1)) ? _SELECTED_POINTS[0].geometry.location.lng() : _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lng(),
        ToLatitude: _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lat(),
        ToLongitude: _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lng(),
        DistanceType: 'Mile',
        DistanceCalculateType: (i == (_SELECTED_POINTS.length - 1)) ? 'TotalDistance' : 'PickDrop',
        TotalPrice: '0',
        TotalDistance: '0'
    };

    console.log(dist);
    distancecost.push({
        dist
    });
}

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/Dashboard/CalculateDistanceAndPrice',
    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ 'distanceCost': distancecost })),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('DistanceCalculation Response:: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

}

Here is the Jsonresult action method:

[image]

Edit:
As Nicholas suggested, I change the type but still its not working, AFAIK POST we use when we are inserting any data and PUT when updating any data but here I'm just fetching the data by calculating the distance between each point:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/Dashboard/CalculateDistanceAndPrice',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'distanceCost': distancecost }),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('DistanceCalculation Response:: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

[image]

Edit: 
I changed the object creation but still no luck:

```
var DistanceCost = new Object();
    DistanceCost.PlaceId = _SELECTED_POINTS[i].place_id;
    DistanceCost.PointSequence = _SELECTED_POINTS[i].PointSequence;
    DistanceCost.controlId = "";//_SELECTED_POINTS[i].controlId,
    DistanceCost.FromLatitude = (i == (_SELECTED_POINTS.length - 1)) ? _SELECTED_POINTS[0].geometry.location.lat() : _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lat();
    DistanceCost.FromLongitude = (i == (_SELECTED_POINTS.length - 1)) ? _SELECTED_POINTS[0].geometry.location.lng() : _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lng();
    DistanceCost.ToLatitude = _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lat();
    DistanceCost.ToLongitude = _SELECTED_POINTS[i].geometry.location.lng();
    DistanceCost.DistanceType = 'Mile';
    DistanceCost.DistanceCalculateType = (i == (_SELECTED_POINTS.length - 1)) ? 'TotalDistance' : 'PickDrop';
    DistanceCost.TotalPrice = '0';
    DistanceCost.TotalDistance = '0';
```

Comment: I even tried with JSON.stringify({ 'distanceCost': distancecost }), it completely sending object null not even displaying the property names

Comment: You can’t add data to a request of get-type.

Comment: Either you change to POST or to PUT. If you want keep GET, you have to add the data in the query-string of the url.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove quotations of distanceCost
 +>   `data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ distanceCost: distancecost }))`